Error in creating cluster on compute engine
Can you some one help me resolve following error while creating dataproc cluster:
Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/resounding-rune-442220-d5'

I have corrected all the roles for services and dataproc-worker
I have email account with role owner
I am try to create the cluster with minimal specification 1 Node and 50 GB, but failing

